# Adding captcha check into jquery form validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate form script and need to add it a captcha script. if form check returns true,than I want the captcha script to be run to kontrol the entered value by the user. How can I do this? I mean where should I write the captcha check script? thanks.

Form validate is as follows:

```
$("#form1").validate({

    errorPlacement: function(error,element){                                          
            return true;
            }, 
    errorClass: "invalid"

});
```

Captcha script is as follows:

```
$.post("post.php?"+$("#form1").serialize(), {

        }, function(response){

        if(response==1)
        {
            $("#after_submit").html('');
            $("#Send").after('<label class="success" id="after_submit">Your message has been submitted.</label>');
            change_captcha();
            clear_form();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#after_submit").html('');
            $("#Send").after('<label class="error" id="after_submit">Error ! invalid captcha code .</label>');
        }


    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the recaptcha code in the submitHandler.

```
$("#form1").validate({

    errorPlacement: function(error,element){                                          
            return true;
            }, 
    errorClass: "invalid",

    submitHandler: function() {
        //you can add the recaptcha code here
    }

});
```

If all the validations are succeeded then the control will reach in the submitHandler and there you can check your recaptcha code.